# python dataframe replace value in one column

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to replace 1.0 to red, 2.0 to yellow, but just in one column 'code' in the dataframe

```
  code brand character
   1.0  1.0   ..
   1.0  2.0   ..
   2.0  3.0   ..
```

I want to get the dataframe like:

```
  code brand character
   red  1.0   ..
   red  2.0   ..
yellow  3.0   ..
```

I tried with replace function as:

```
df = df.replace(1.0, "red")
```

but it replace all '1.0', not just in column 'code' and I tried

```
df["code"].replace({"1.0": "red", "2.0": "yellow"}
```

but I just got part of the dataframe of column 'code',I still want get the whole dataframe with just column ' code' updated.

Many thanks!

Comment: `df["code"] = df["code"].replace({"1.0": "red", "2.0": "yellow"}`

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like:

```
df['code'] = df['code'].replace(['1.0'],'red')
```

This should replace the value in the 'code' column, but still keep the entire dataframe for you.